# Naming convention of event components in Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function

Tags: c#, events, azure-functions, naming-conventions

I am working with Azure Functions, In my application we are using Http Trigger Azure Function to receive the notification events(i.e. `UserCreatedEvent, UserDetailsUpdatedEvent` etc.) and after this Azure Function publishing that event into Service Bus Topic. We have created subscriptions for this Service Bus topic with filter. For each subscription we have corresponding Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function. These Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Functions sending the notifications.

So should we use EventHanlder(`UserCreatedEventHandler`) or EventProcessor(`UserCreatedEventProcessor`) naming convention in these Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function?

Can someone provide guidance on choosing a naming convention for these event components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, particularly their is no such definite rules(steps to follow) for naming a SeviceBus Trigger or azure function trigger part's of code. It only depends on how we write code for our understanding and for further use of the code.

Actually,

- `EventProcessor`  is meant for events(request) coming/going from the Service Bus Topic and then transferring information about it by mails or messages or logs to end user(the person it is required to send the information).
- `EventHandler`  is meant for handling the requests within the scope of your project.

It is good to use the  `UserCreatedEventProcessor`  as it is giving clear information on what code is doing and also depends on your project requirement/team understanding.

For further you can refer  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host)  for more information on  `EventProcessor`  usage in Azure Functions.

Comment: Are you saying I should go with `EventProcessor` naming convention? As event is already published into service bus topic and this azure function is just processing that message and triggering the notification.

Comment: Yeah you are right.